# Android / Java Pattern Matching

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching, sharedpreferences

For some reason I am unable to get the pattern match for "preference_network_" followed by any anything else as a single string.  I want to be able to test if a preference key contains "preference_network_" using the key.matches() method.  How can I get this working, I've tried a few things with no success.  Thanks is advance.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for not clarifying.  All of these solutions I can perform and know about.  What I am trying to do is use the "key.matches(String regularExpression)" function where key is a parameter to the onSharedPreferenceChangeListener method.  This is what I am having trouble to get working.

And I'm aware I do not have to use this, I can use the startsWith just fine.  I was just wondering.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solutions without using patterns:

```
str.startsWith("preference_network_");
str.contains("preference_network_");
```

With patterns

```
// the same as contains.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("preference_network_");
p.matcher(str).find(); 

// the same as startsWith.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^preference_network_");
p.matcher(str).find();
```

If you want to use `matches()` you have to writer full pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^preference_network_.*");
p.matcher(str).matches();
```

Because matches performs as if your pattern starts with ^ and ends with $, i.e.

`Pattern.compile("^something$").matcher(str).find()` is the same as `Pattern.compile("something").matcher(str).matches()`

Comment: contains looks for the parameter string in every position. In the question he states that looks for ""preference_network_" followed by any anything else"

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
boolean matches = myString.startsWith("preference_network_");
```